# get sum for each row - but new rows can occur

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

roles:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | role_a |
| 2 | role_b |

user_data:

| user | start | stop | role_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 09:00:00 | 2022-01-01 10:00:00 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 09:00:00 | 2022-01-01 10:00:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 10:00:00 | 2022-01-02 11:00:00 | 2 |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 10:00:00 | 2022-01-02 11:00:00 | 2 |

I need to get a recordset where there is a row for each role_id... A result like this:

| user | role_a_hours | role_b_hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |

It could be a select like this:

```
select user,sum(case when role_id=1 then timediff(stop,start) else 0 end) role_a,sum(case when role_id=2 then timediff(stop,start) else 0 end) role_b from roles inner join user_data on role_id=id group by id;
```

But the problem is that if a new role occurs there is no column for it. So is it possible to do this dynamically - so a new column just appears in the view when there is new data in the new role?
So the result is like the table above..

Thanks.

Comment: Dynamic pivot in MySQL needs in [dynamic SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html) always.

Comment: ok... Is it possible to use dynamic SQL in a view..?

Comment: Dynamic SQL cannot be used in view - prepared statement can be used in compound statement (for example, stored procedure) only. But dynamic SQL may alter current view.